# getting the length of a file using stat() in C

Tags: c, data-structures, stat

I have a file whose length, I wanted to get using the stat() function in the code below:

```
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
 int filesize, i;


 if(file==NULL)
{
        printf("Could not open mea.dat!\n");
    return ; 
}

        struct stat st;
        stat(filename, &st);
        filesize = st.st_size;
  .........
```

but when i checked the filesize, i got the value 1504 even though just by counting numerically, the length of the file content is 101 and as such the filesize should have been 102 as wel. where am i missing it?

Comment: Uninitialized memory maybe, check the return code of stat and use perror to see why it is failing.

Comment: @Zeta: Because file is of type FILE*, and fstat takes an integer file descriptor? (*Hint*: fileno() )

Comment: @janneb,i tried that as well..stat(fileno(file), &st); filesize = st.st_size; but didn't work. i am getting the value in bytes. just need to get it back in ints or something..the exact value should be 102 but now am getting very high numbers..1504

Comment: You give `stat` a file name, which is correct. It's generally recommended to use `fstat` instead, which gets `FILE *`. Did you test the file size with a simple `ls`? It isn't clear what "counting numerically" means. With binary files, what you see with an editor may not be what's in the file.

Comment: @ugoren, with fstat() i get a much more bigger number: 1606664232 while with stat() i get 1504. Could these functions be returning byte values instead of int?

Comment: Did you follow @ergosys's suggestion, and checked the return value? Maybe `stat` fails, and you look at uninitialized data.

Comment: @ugoren, what return value suggests that stat succeeded?

Comment: It may be useful to read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> where am i missing it?

When the size returned by `stat()` and the size you got by *counting numerically* (whatever that means) differ, the chances are that your counting is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the return value of `stat()` before deciding to trust the value in the struct

```
        if (stat(filename, &st)) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        filesize = st.st_size;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the file in question a sparse file?

With sparse files blocks of data are not there on disk but are reported by ls -l.  Here is an example sparse file:

```
ls -ls sparse
2 -rw-r--r-- 1 root sys 1048577 Feb 20 12:58 sparse
```

The leftmost 2 is the actual number of blocks used, the 1088577 is the number of bytes allocated ot the file (not all are actually on disk).  Since 2 blocks (usually 1024 on the box I did this) do not add up to 1058577, you can see a sparse file this way.